# Syntax For Searching the Microsoft Update Catalog

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Microsoft allows download of Windows Updates, drivers and other upgrades from the Microsoft Update Catalog: http://catalog.update.microsoft.com .

Unfortunately there seems to be no search syntax available to do **advanced searches** such as OR, NOT and similar. Does anyone know if this is possible? For example: I keep getting a lot of Windows 7 Embedded updates listed along with Windows 7 updates as well as outdated and deprecated updates.

Try this default search: **Windows 7 x64 security updates**

Comment: [How can I install hotfixes silently to speed up a fresh Windows 7 installation?](https://superuser.com/questions/746799/how-can-i-install-hotfixes-silently-to-speed-up-a-fresh-windows-7-installation).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install hotfixes silently to speed up a fresh Windows 7 installation?](https://superuser.com/questions/746799/how-can-i-install-hotfixes-silently-to-speed-up-a-fresh-windows-7-installation)

Answer (score 0):

To Search in Microsoft Update Catalog, we can Use below two Operation..

1. +: this plus operator ensures that both words should be exist. so it is working like AND operator.
2. : Minus operator is used to Exclude some specific Word. Like "Windows"-"Security" : so this will result all update which contains Windows but does not contain Security.

For example :-
AND(+): "Microsoft .NET Framework"+"Windows 10"
NOT (-) : ("Framework")-"Update for"-"Security"-"intel"-"Quality".

Thank you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).